# bounce function in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, bounce

```
def bounce(self):
        self.velocity[0] = -self.velocity[0]
        self.velocity[1] = randint(-10,10)
```

Hey, I would like to recode this bounce function but I have no clue, how should I do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "recode this bounce function"?

Comment: Do you mean a bounce with gravity, with each subsequent bounce being less, like a ball bouncing on the ground?

Comment: we also `have no clue` what you mean. What result do you expect?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, what I want to achieve is that when the ball bounces with the walls it should bounce back randomly

Answer (score 1):

According to physics, the best and most natural-looking result would be to not change `self.velocity[1]`. Assuming that `self.velocity[0]` is on the X-axis, and `self.velocity[1]` is on the Y-axis, then if you are bouncing into any wall on the X-axis (left or right), `self.velocity[1]` shouldn't change, just the velocity on the X-axis should get reversed. In case you'd want to do the same thing for collision on the Y-axis, you should just do the same but with `self.velocity[1]` instead of `self.velocity[0]`.

A diagram of a ball bounce that keeps the same angle:

[image: Diagram of ball bounce]

On the other hand, if what you want is to make it bounce of in a random direction (which wouldn't look as natural), your current function is great (although if you're using pygame you could convert `self.velocity` into a `Vector2` object to make it cleaner).